# how to generate alignment padding in idl file while running anchor build

Tags: idl

zero_copy and repr(c) are used before state struct to handle the over-stack problem.
While generating the idl json file by anchor build, no padding field is generated following #[repr(C)] alignment rule. How to generate these padding fields automatically?
Is there a parameter I can use while running 'anchor build' for this. I need this to fetch and deserialize the state account correctly.

```
#[account(zero_copy(unsafe))]
#[repr(C)]
pub struct SSS {
pub u8 f1,
pub u64 f2,
pub u8 f3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The padding will always get created automatically without your knowledge. If you create this struct as `repr(C)` and get its size, you'll have:

```
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<SSS>());
```

give you an answer of `24`, which means 7 bytes of padding after `f1` and 7 bytes after `f3`. You can declare it explicitly if needed:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct SSS {
    f1: u8,
    padding_after_f1: [u8; 7],
    f2: u64,
    f3: u8,
    padding_after_f3: [u8; 7],
}
```

Which will also give you a size of `24`.